# Create a click event on ListViewItem programmatically in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I'm making a WPF app, this app has a UserControl, which has a list view.

I tried to create a click event listener but i never got it to work right, and i havend find anything to solve it

I fill this list view items with an object like this:

```
List<AsesoriaClass> listaAsesorias = phpClass.getListaAsesoriasAsesor(asesor.ID);
            foreach (var asesoria in listaAsesorias)
            {
                AsesoriaTable data = new AsesoriaTable(asesoria.AsesoriaID.ToString(), asesoria.ClienteNombre + " " + asesoria.ClienteApellidos, asesoria.FechaInicio.ToString(), asesoria.FechaFinal.ToString());
                this.ListView.Items.Add(data);
            }
```

And this is the XAML of the User Control:

```
<ListView x:Name="ListView">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="ID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Id}" Width="100"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Cliente" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Cliente}" Width="300"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Inicio" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Inicio}" Width="200"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Final" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Final}" Width="200"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

I want to make a click listener so, when i click on an item something happens (to start i just want it to show a mesage box). how do i do this?

Comment: Please define, "never got it right" or better yet, place the code so that it's possible to help you with fixing the code. Also please clarify, do you want to create the event handler at run time or do you want to define it in XAML?

Comment: Sorry. As you can see on the code, i create the items programmatically, so, i want to asign an on click event on those items and has to be done programmatically, and it has to have an index, p.e.: if i click on the second item, the index of the event will be 1 and so on. I hope i explained myself correctly. Feel free to ask any other question.

Comment: It's a ListView. Just bind its SelectedItem or SelectedIndex property. Alternatively, attach a handler to its SelectionChanged event.

Comment: I'd recommend using data binding to add the items to the `ListView` and also for determine which item is selected as @Clemens suggested in his comment which I just upvoted. WPF allows you to to a lot of work declaratively as opposed to writing out the logic in event handlers.

Comment: Instead of programmatically adding elements to the ListView's Items collection, you would usually bind its ItemsSource property to a collection-type property of a view model class (google MVVM). The view model would also have a property for the selected item, to which the ListView's SelectedItem would be bound.

Comment: ` ListView.SelectionChanged += LstOnSelectionChanged;` where `LstOnSelectionChanged` is a method. `private void LstOnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Anything");
        }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply attach an Event Handler on `SelectionChanged`. Like this

```
 ListView.SelectionChanged += LstOnSelectionChanged;
```

Where `LstOnSelectionChanged` is a method.

```
private void LstOnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) 
{ 
  MessageBox.Show("Anything"); 
}
```